# HTML indenter written in Python

Tags: python, html, indentation

I am looking for a free (as in freedom) HTML indenter (or re-indenter) written in Python (module or command line). I don't need to filter HTML with a white list. I just want to indent (or re-indent) HTML source to make it more readable. For example, say I have the following code:

```
<ul><li>Item</li><li>Item
</li></ul>
```

the output could be something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

*Note: I am not looking for an interface to a non-Python software (for example Tidy, written in C), but a 100% Python script.*

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup has a function called `prettify` which does this.
[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150108/python-how-to-pretty-print-html-into-a-file)

Comment: **Except it doesn't.** It only gives 1 space per level of indentation, and that isn't parameterizable - the OP wanted 4 spaces per level. It also doesn't allow you specify tags you don't want indented, e.g. `<a>`, or inline elements like `<b>, <i>, <strong>` etc. It essentially has zero parameterizability. This is why you see so many questions asking for this, over a decade.

Answer (score 8):

you can use the built-in module `xml.dom.minidom`'s `toprettyxml` function:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> x = minidom.parseString("<ul><li>Item</li><li>Item\n</li></ul>")
>>> print x.toprettyxml()
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ul>
    <li>
        Item
    </li>
    <li>
        Item
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to remove that `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` line?

Comment: you can just remove the first line `'\n'.join(x.toprettyxml().splitlines()[1:])` (not the best solution but will do the work)

Comment: To remove the header, where `header='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'` (that's the current default xml header), this: `re.sub(re.escape(header), '', xml, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE).strip()` should do it (`import re` beforehand).

Comment: To remove `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` I used this `html = html[23:-1]` It gets rid of blank line at end too.

Comment: To remove blank lines it is much safer to use `.strip()`

Comment: Great solution to avoid additional libraries, but the XML parser is more fragile with dirty HTML, and you can get errors like `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)` -- it may take a bit more effort to clean up the source, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821725/xml-parsers-expat-expaterror-not-well-formed-invalid-token

Answer (score 7):

## Using BeautifulSoup

There are a dozen ways to use the BeautifulSoup module and its prettify function. Here are some examples to get you started.

### With a command line

```
$ python -m BeautifulSoup < somefile.html > prettyfile.html
```

### Within VIM (manually)

You don't have to write the file back to disk if you don't want to, but I included the step that would get the identical effect as the commandline example.

```
$ vi somefile.html
:!python -m BeautifulSoup < %
:w prettyfile.html
```

### Within VIM (define key-mapping)

In ~/.vimrc define:

```
nmap =h !python -m BeautifulSoup < %<CR>
```

Then, when you open a file in vim and it needs beautification

```
$vi somefile.html
=h
:w prettyfile.html
```

Once again, saving the beautification is optional.

### Python Shell

```
$ python
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as parse_html_string
>>> from os import path
>>> uglyfile = path.abspath('somefile.html')
>>> path.isfile(uglyfile)
True
>>> prettyfile = path.abspath(path.join('.', 'prettyfile.html'))
>>> path.exists(prettyfile)
>>> doc = None
>>> with open(uglyfile, 'r') as infile, open(prettyfile, 'w') as outfile:
...     # Assuming very simple case
...     htmldocstr = infile.read()
...     doc = parse_html_string(htmldocstr)
...     outfile.write(doc.prettify())

# That's it; you can manually manipulate the dom too though
>>> scripts = doc.findAll('script')
>>> meta = doc.findAll('meta')
>>> print doc.prettify()
[imagine beautiful html here]

>>> import jsbeautifier
>>> print jsbeautifier.beautify(script.string)
[imagine beautiful script here]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also the [html5print](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5print/) module. Key features from the description page:

- Pretty print HTML as well as embedded CSS and JavaScript within it
- Pretty print pure CSS and JavaScript
- Try to fix fragmented HTML5
- Try to fix HTML with broken unicode encoding
- Try to guess encoding of the document, and in some cases manage to convert 8-bit byte code back into correct UTF-8 format
- Support both Python 2 and 3

Comment: This uses bs4 behind the scenes, see other answers for bs4 prettify.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my pure python solution:

```py
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString as string_to_dom

def prettify(string, html=True):
    dom = string_to_dom(string)
    ugly = dom.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
    split = list(filter(lambda x: len(x.strip()), ugly.split('\n')))
    if html:
        split = split[1:]
    pretty = '\n'.join(split)
    return pretty

def pretty_print(html):
    print(prettify(html))
```

When used on your block of html:

```py
html = """<ul><li>Item</li><li>Item</li></ul>"""
pretty_print(html)
```

I get:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm getting a "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 110" when using the utf-8 string from lxml html/etree output.

Comment: ~@RodManiego Same, did you manage to fix it?