# How to convert the http get response from html to json format (from kaggle.com)

Tags: python, html, json, xmltodict, xml-to-json

I tried below code to get a http response from kaggle.com.
Kaggle response is in html format and I wanted to convert it to json format for the ease of further processing.

```
import requests
import json

username = 'vgtgayan'
base_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/'
url = base_url+str(username)

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.r.headers["content-type"])
```

Output:

```
200
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Above code is common to all methods below.

Attempt1:

```
r.json()
```

Error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Attempt2:

```
import xmltodict
import xmltojson

json_ = xmltojson.parse(r.text)
```

Error:

```
ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 22, column 70
```

Attempt 3:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
dict = xmltodict.parse(ElementTree.tostring(ElementTree.parse(path).getroot()))
```

Error:

```
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token):
```

Reference:
[xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821725/xml-parsers-expat-expaterror-not-well-formed-invalid-token)

Each of the above attempts were ended up giving errors.
Please help me to achieve this task.

Below is the html response I am getting,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">



<head>

  <title>V.G.T. Gayan | Novice | Kaggle</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

  <meta name="description" content="Kaggle profile for V.G.T. Gayan" />

  <meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#008ABC" />

  <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" type="text/javascript">

    window["pageRequestStartTime"] = 1641792835393;

    window["pageRequestEndTime"] = 1641792835435;

    window["initialPageLoadStartTime"] = new Date().getTime();

  </script>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google-analytics.com" crossorigin="anonymous" /><link rel="preconnect" href="https://stats.g.doubleclick.net" /><link rel="preconnect" href="https://storage.googleapis.com" /><link rel="preconnect" href="https://apis.google.com" />

  <link href="/static/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="/static/json/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials">





  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Google+Material+Icons"

    rel="preload" as="style" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"

    rel="preload" as="style" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Google+Material+Icons"

    rel="stylesheet" media="print" id="async-google-font-1" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter:400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"

    rel="stylesheet" media="print" id="async-google-font-2" />

  <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" type="text/javascript">

    const styleSheetIds = ["async-google-font-1", "async-google-font-2"];

    styleSheetIds.forEach(function (id) {

      document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("load", function() {

        this.media = "all";

      });

    });

  </script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/assets/vendor.css?v=a39c9d14b7e6072d0f7a" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/assets/app.css?v=453de5392c911bfbccf0" />

  

    

 

      <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==">

        try{(function(a,s,y,n,c,h,i,d,e){d=s.createElement("style");

        d.appendChild(s.createTextNode(""));s.head.appendChild(d);d=d.sheet;

        y=y.map(x => d.insertRule(x + "{ opacity: 0 !important }"));

        h.start=1*new Date;h.end=i=function(){y.forEach(x => x<d.cssRules.length ? d.deleteRule(x) : {})};

        (a[n]=a[n]||[]).hide=h;setTimeout(function(){i();h.end=null},c);h.timeout=c;

        })(window,document,['.site-header-react__nav'],'dataLayer',2000,{'GTM-52LNT9S':true});}catch(ex){}

    </script>

    <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==">

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }

        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-12629138-1', {

            'optimize_id': 'GTM-52LNT9S',

            'displayFeaturesTask': null,

            'send_page_view': false,

            'content_group1': 'Users'

        });

    </script>

    <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-12629138-1"></script>



  

    

    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.kaggle.com/vgtgayan/home" />

    <meta property="og:title" content="V.G.T. Gayan | Novice" />

    <meta property="og:description" content="Kaggle profile for V.G.T. Gayan" />

    <meta property="og:type" content="profile" />

    <meta property="og:username" content="vgtgayan" />

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" /> 

    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.kaggle.com/static/images/tiers/Novice@192.png" />

    <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Novice" />





  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Kaggle" /> 

  

    



  

    



  

    

    

<script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" type="text/javascript">

    var Kaggle = window.Kaggle || {};



    Kaggle.Current = {

        antiForgeryToken: 'CfDJ8LdUzqlsSWBPr4Ce3rb9VL9za2FFB-rFm9iuPAm8PKLq9TqJiAHT4UmlnyzfLtHBrGjL5o2brrzKiVOqcKYybNKzrGn4e1wSl09TIhcFoh_3ivZ3ndFbLCUM9zaxUWdhs8JzSLYm5l9RM1a-bbh55aw',

        isAnonymous: true,

        analyticsToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2NDE3OTM3MzUsIlVzZXJJZCI6MH0.vEUaJcUG88jwDqImiQoQtQU8-jui4Gdp6xihpLlls0U',

        analyticsTokenExpiry: 15,

        

        

        

        

        

        

        

        enableRapidash: true, 

    }

        Kaggle.Current.log = function(){};

        Kaggle.Current.warn = function(){};



    var decodeUserDisplayName = function () {

        var escapedUserDisplayName = Kaggle.Current.userDisplayNameEscaped || "";

        try {

            var textVersion = new DOMParser().parseFromString(escapedUserDisplayName, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;

            if (textVersion) {

                return textVersion;

            }

        } catch(ex) {}

        return escapedUserDisplayName;

    }

    Kaggle.Current.userDisplayName = decodeUserDisplayName();

</script>



    



<script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" type="text/javascript">

    var Kaggle = window.Kaggle || {};

    Kaggle.PageMessages = [];

</script>







    <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==">window['useKaggleAnalytics'] = true;</script>



  <script id="gapi-target" nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" defer

    async></script>

  <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" src="/static/assets/runtime.js?v=f84cf2a36564689cb2b3" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>

  <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" src="/static/assets/vendor.js?v=26a3487f6f4d622267d2" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>

  <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" src="/static/assets/app.js?v=36d0e4e3f41dd27e5515" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>

    <script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" type="text/javascript">

      window.kaggleStackdriverConfig = {

        key: 'AIzaSyA4eNqUdRRskJsCZWVz-qL655Xa5JEMreE',

        projectId: 'kaggle-161607',

        service: 'web-fe',

        version: 'ci',

        userId: '0'

      }

    </script>

</head>



<body data-turbolinks="false">

  <main>

    













<div id="site-container"></div>

<div data-component-name="NavigationContainer" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1 0 auto;"></div><script class="kaggle-component" nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==">var Kaggle=window.Kaggle||{};Kaggle.State=Kaggle.State||[];Kaggle.State.push({"navigationType":"BOTH_NAV"});performance && performance.mark && performance.mark("NavigationContainer.componentCouldBootstrap");</script>

<div id="site-body" class="hide">

    

<div data-component-name="ProfileContainerReact" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex: 1 0 auto;"></div><script class="kaggle-component" nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==">var Kaggle=window.Kaggle||{};Kaggle.State=Kaggle.State||[];Kaggle.State.push({"userId":8257495,"displayName":"V.G.T. Gayan","country":"Sri Lanka","region":"Western Province","city":"Colombo","gitHubUserName":null,"twitterUserName":null,"linkedInUrl":null,"websiteUrl":null,"occupation":"Research \u0026 Development Engineer","organization":"Synopsys Inc","bio":null,"userLastActive":"2022-01-10T03:58:03.07Z","userJoinDate":"2021-09-01T11:53:55.643Z","performanceTier":"novice","performanceTierCategory":"competitions","activePaneTier":"novice","activePaneCategory":"unspecified","userUrl":"/vgtgayan","userAvatarUrl":"https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-avatars/images/default-thumb.png","email":null,"canEdit":false,"canCreateDatasets":true,"userName":"vgtgayan","activePane":"home","totalDatasets":0,"totalOrganizations":0,"competitionsSummary":{"tier":"novice","totalResults":0,"rankPercentage":0.9691485,"rankOutOf":173152,"rankCurrent":null,"rankHighest":null,"totalGoldMedals":0,"totalSilverMedals":0,"totalBronzeMedals":0,"highlights":[],"summaryType":"competitions"},"scriptsSummary":{"tier":"novice","totalResults":1,"rankPercentage":0.1549871,"rankOutOf":203004,"rankCurrent":null,"rankHighest":null,"totalGoldMedals":0,"totalSilverMedals":0,"totalBronzeMedals":0,"highlights":[],"summaryType":"notebooks"},"discussionsSummary":{"tier":"novice","totalResults":0,"rankPercentage":0.022529345,"rankOutOf":267429,"rankCurrent":null,"rankHighest":null,"totalGoldMedals":0,"totalSilverMedals":0,"totalBronzeMedals":0,"highlights":[],"summaryType":"discussion"},"datasetsSummary":{"tier":"novice","totalResults":0,"rankPercentage":0.13677031,"rankOutOf":54098,"rankCurrent":null,"rankHighest":null,"totalGoldMedals":0,"totalSilverMedals":0,"totalBronzeMedals":0,"highlights":[],"summaryType":"datasets"},"pageMessages":null,"followers":{"type":"following","count":0,"list":[],"containsSelf":false,"maxCountReached":false},"following":{"type":"following","count":0,"list":[],"containsSelf":false,"maxCountReached":false},"canSeeFollowers":false,"canSeeCallToAction":true,"canSeeNotifications":true,"canSeeAtMentions":true,"totalScripts":1,"isAdmin":false,"isEditing":false,"userAllowsUserMessages":true,"@wf": "Users.Models.ProfileDtoWireFormat"});performance && performance.mark && performance.mark("ProfileContainerReact.componentCouldBootstrap");</script>

<script nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==" type="text/x-mathjax-config">

    MathJax.Hub.Config({

    "HTML-CSS": {

    preferredFont: "TeX",

    availableFonts: ["STIX", "TeX"],

    linebreaks: {

    automatic: true

    },

    EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50)

    },

    tex2jax: {

    inlineMath: [["\\(", "\\)"], ["\\\\(", "\\\\)"]],

    displayMath: [["$$", "$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"]],

    processEscapes: true,

    ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno"

    },

    TeX: {

    noUndefined: {

    attributes: {

    mathcolor: "red",

    mathbackground: "#FFEEEE",

    mathsize: "90%"

    }

    }

    },

    Macros: {

    href: "{}"

    },

    skipStartupTypeset: true,

    messageStyle: "none",

    extensions: [],

    });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" nonce="VmwzDvxUO596o90cb7qq6Q==">

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    const useProdHosts = ["www.kaggle.com", "admin.kaggle.com"];

    const subdomain = useProdHosts.includes(window.location.hostname) ? "www" : "staging";



    const lib = document.createElement("script");

    lib.type = "text/javascript";

    lib.src = `https://${subdomain}.kaggleusercontent.com/static/mathjax/2.7.9/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML`;

    head.appendChild(lib);

  });

</script>





</div>









  </main>

</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this html_to_json package
`pip install html-to-json`

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html_to_json

username = 'vgtgayan'
base_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/'
url = base_url+str(username)

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)

html_string = r.text
output_json = html_to_json.convert(html_string)
print(output_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use html_to_json

```
import requests
import json
import html_to_json
username = 'vgtgayan'
base_url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/'
url = base_url+str(username)
r = requests.get(url)
html_response = requests.get(url)
html_string = html_response.text
output_json = html_to_json.convert(html_string)
print(output_json)
```