# Python script runs on Google Colab but not locally

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, xml-parsing, xmltodict

I was trying to run this script in a VS Code pyhton notebook and got that error.

```
import requests
import xmltodict
xml = requests.get('https://websvc.biocyc.org/getxml?id=META:TYRFUMCAT-PWY')
dbiocyc = xmltodict.parse(xml.text)
```

`ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 24, column 65`

Running it on Google Colab I got the right output.

Both at Python 3.10.12, xmltodict 0.13.0, requests 2.31.0

Someone can help me figure out why is it happening?

I was expecting get a dictionary with the information in the web page, but I got an error.

---

Update 1:

Following rasjani comment, I compared both requests.get() output saving them as a .xml file.

On Google Colab it was saving the page as it really is.

Locally, another page is being saved instead of the one I want, a HTML page, which has and XML forbidden character on line 24.

[Left: File that I get running script locally -- Right: File that I get running at Google Colab - I want to get this locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRxoN.jpg)

Comment: Save the file and inspect whats on line 24 ?  You aint checking what was the status code of requests.get() either ..

Comment: Try specifying the encoding to ensure consistency.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821725/xml-parsers-expat-expaterror-not-well-formed-invalid-token)

Comment: @rasjani I did it now and request.get() isn't getting the right data, thanks for the help, now I need to figure out why it's happening.

Comment: @ImanMohammadi I think I don't have this option using requests.get(), do I?

Comment: @pho, no, in this one user was importing a xml from it's system, my error seems to be in requests.get()

Comment: You can specify the encoding to ensure consistency using `requests.get()`. `xml_content` and `dbiocyc`.

Comment: @luizgsm  Since the "failing" looks like just a html that asks you to create an account - it might be that the site you are trying to fetch data off is trying to prevent you from fetching the page by adding additional hurdle that you need to create a user account and authenticate..

Comment: @rasjani But running in Google Colab give us the right output. Access web adress give us the xml page too.

Comment: @luizgsm They might be blocking your IP -- collab code probably originates from google ip ranges and never gets the rate limited or blocked ?