# HTML Tidy strip tags

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, htmltidy

I'm working on dynamic template for bootstrap, and i'm using HTML Tidy. However it seem HTML Tidy remove specific tags, for example:

```
      <b class="caret"></b>
```

How to supposed solve this ?
my options/config is

```
     $options = array('indent'  => true,
                 'wrap'   => '300',
                "indent-spaces" => 4,
                'clean'=>false  );
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem. You can add `&nbsp;` in the tags. Html tidy will remove the tags since it thinks nothing will be displayed in any case, for example:

`<b class="caret">&nbsp;</b>`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issues as both of you, the `&nbsp;` helped, i just wanted to mention that
if you work responsible, that you also would have to put a `&nbsp;` into the collapse-icon in the navbar, see following:

```
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

should be:

```
            <span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="icon-bar">&nbsp;</span>
```