# Parse XML with Python with fewer lines

Tags: python, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using BS4 in some Python to make a raw string look like good looking XML.

I'm using this:

```
fileText = (BeautifulSoup(fileText, "xml").prettify())
```

It gives me output like this:

```
<foobar>
  <foo>
  bar
  </foo>
  <foo>
  bar2
  </foo>
</foobar>
```

but i'd like:

```
<foobar>
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <foo>bar2</foo>
</foobar>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This and below: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing

Answer (score 0):

From [Jayesh Bhoot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16505750/4066647):

```
from lxml import etree, html

doc = html.fromstring(fileText)
print(etree.tostring(doc, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

And as per dspjm's comment to the answer linked above, this works just as well:

```
print(html.tostring(doc, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True, method='xml'))
```

The only condition is that `method='xml'` is required when using `html.tostring`.

The output:

```
<foobar>
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <foo>bar2</foo>
</foobar>
```