# How do I format a messy html source code? python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote code in python that use the HTML source, using BeautifulSoup.
The HTML I'm getting is very messy. How can I make the HTML source look nicely?

Here's the [website](https://tulanehullabaloo.com/31772/no-photo/czech-elections-us-frustration/)

This is how I'm getting the html source (part of it):

```
    property="article:tag" content="ally" /><meta
property="article:tag" content="harvey weinstein" /><meta
property="article:tag" content="pratiksha parulekar" /><meta
property="article:tag" content="rape culture" /><meta
property="article:section" content="No Photo" /><meta
property="article:published_time" content="2017-10-25T22:28:46-05:00" /><meta
property="article:modified_time" content="2017-10-25T22:44:29-05:00" /><meta
property="og:updated_time" content="2017-10-25T22:44:29-05:00" /><meta
name="twitter:card" content="summary" /><meta
name="twitter:description" content="For men, professing disgust at sexual assault allegations is not sufficient; male allies must also hold friends who harass women accountable." /><meta
name="twitter:title" content="To combat sexual harassment, men must hold peers accountable &bull; The Tulane Hullabaloo" /><link
rel='dns-prefetch' href='//cdn.jsdelivr.net' /><link
rel='dns-prefetch' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com' /><link
rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' /><link
rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' /><link
```

What can i do?

Comment: *"Beauty is in the eye of the beholder"*. What do you mean by "Look Nice"? I don't really think that this is a programming question.

Comment: look the html source that i add. the open tag is located at the end. @s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : How to Pretty print html into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150108/python-how-to-pretty-print-html-into-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [the doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing)

```
print(yoursoup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'prettify' the HTML, as you are using Beautiful Soup, you can do something in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150108/python-how-to-pretty-print-html-into-a-file).

Bear in mind that the import has changed since that answer and it's now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Probably some fields changed since then, you can find more examples [in the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)