# Can't figure out how to invoke html5Tidy from Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, htmltidy

For Python 3.5.

Can someone please point me to some documentation for using *html5tidy* with Python 3? I'm amazed that multiple searches don't return anything.

In Python 3, the documentation in *html5tidy.py* states:

```
"""
HTML5Tidy
=========

Simple wrapper around html5lib & lxml.etree to "tidy" html in the wild to
well-formed xml/html

Usage
-----

    >>> from html5tidy import tidy
    >>> tidy('some text')
    '<html><head/><body>some text</body></html>'

Dependencies
------------

* [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/)
* [lxml](http://lxml.de/)
```

Okay, so I have all the pieces:

```
>>> import html5lib
>>> dir(html5lib)
['HTMLParser', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', [and so on]]
>>> 
>>> import lxml
>>> dir(lxml)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', [and so on]]
```

BUT I note that *dir(tidy)* returns only double-underscore results:

```
>>> from html5tidy import tidy
>>> dir(tidy)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', [and so on...]'__subclasshook__']
```

So I open a file containing HTML as *untidiedHTML*.

```
>>> print(untidiedHTML)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="ng-app" lang="en" ng-app="TH" style="" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
 <head ng-controller="DZHeadController">
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
  <title ng-bind="service.title">
   What the Heck Is OAuth? - DZone Security
  </title>
  <link href="WhatIsOAuth0200_files/tranquility.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body class="tranquility" >
 ... and so on...
```

Then per the HTML5 tidy documentation I try:

```
from html5tidy import tidy
tidiedHTML = tidy(untidiedHTML)
```

That produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[path to my Python source file].py", line 50, in <module>
    tidiedHTML = tidy(untidiedHTML)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/html5tidy.py", line 61, in tidy
    parts = [parser.parse(src, encoding=encoding, parseMeta=parseMeta, useChardet=useChardet)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 289, in parse
    self._parse(stream, False, None, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 130, in _parse
    self.tokenizer = _tokenizer.HTMLTokenizer(stream, parser=self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/html5lib/_tokenizer.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.stream = HTMLInputStream(stream, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/html5lib/_inputstream.py", line 149, in HTMLInputStream
    return HTMLUnicodeInputStream(source, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parseMeta'
```

I have NO idea what to do. I've searched for documentation that explains how to invoke *html5tidy* from Python 3 but I've come up empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is broken and/or doesn't work with python 3.5. I installed and ran into errors related to html5lib.HTMLParser https://github.com/aleray/html5tidy/blob/master/html5tidy.py#L57

Theres one contributor and the package has not been updated in 6 years

Your options are

- fork the repo, fix the issues and submit a pull-request
- extract the code you need and roll-your-own
- find another library

Comment: Wow -- thank you for that! I was amazed that numerous Web searches weren't returning results. You've explained why that's the case.

Comment: Glad I could help!