# Format a string containing HTML to display with indenting, hierarchy and colors

Tags: python

I'm trying to output the HTML from a webpage, and do it in a formatted way.  For example, I want to make this:
[image]

Look like this:
[image]

My code is:

```
url = "https://dex.raydium.io/#/market/MTc1macY8G2v1MubFxDp4W8cooaSBUZvc2KqaCNwhQE"
page  = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
html_help = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(html_help)
```

I do not wish to print this to a file. I wish to display on screen with coloring and indentation.

Comment: Jupyter doesn't print strings with colors unless you actually want to render HTML itself

Comment: You can use beautifulsoup.[Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150108/how-to-pretty-print-html-to-a-file-with-indentation)

Comment: Welcome aboard.  This should probably be closed as a duplicate.  This doesn’t mean your question is invalid or lacking in any way, only that substantially the same thing was asked before.  And you *are* getting the answers from that dupe ( I second BeautifulSoup’s prettify).  Mind you: the answers dont colorize, so perhaps a separate colorize question is warranted (no idea if that’s been asked before) except that Jupyter/html/bash/ what have you all handle colors differently.

Answer (score 1):

I think this pip package will help you
https://pythonhosted.org/html5print/

Install:

```
pip install html5print
```

Example usage

```
 from html5print import CSSBeautifier
 html = '''<html><body>
   <style>
     .para { margin: 10px 20px; }
 <!-- This is what the function is dealing with-->
 p { color: red; font-style: normal; }
   </style>
 </body></html>'''
print(CSSBeautifier.beautifyTextInHTML(html))
```